# Start another activity with intent-filter inside TWA app created by Bubblewrap

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

I have an android app built with [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap) and want to open an activity when custom link clicked `href="my-app://open-activity"`
My activity is declared like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="open-activity"
                android:scheme="my-app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

but when I click on that link application terminated and get closed.
What's wrong with this code?

Comment: SO is getting useless these days, it used to be very helpful community ..

Comment: were you able to get a solution for this?